# PHP Array Search and Delete

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have two array:

Array 1:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => et1 [supplier_id] => 4 [supplier_product_code] => 00054X [is_active] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => et2 [supplier_id] => 4 [supplier_product_code] => 000558 [is_active] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => et3 [supplier_id] => 5 [supplier_product_code] => 00054X [is_active] => 1 ));
```

Array 2:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([id] => et1 [same_sku] => et3);
```

I need to delete all the same_skus in array1 from array2.

So from my result array I need array1 to be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => et1 [supplier_id] => 4 [supplier_product_code] => 00054X [is_active] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => et2 [supplier_id] => 4 [supplier_product_code] => 000558 [is_active] => 1 ));
```

Code that I have right now does not work.

```
public function search_array($array, $val)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $row)
        {
            if ($row['id'] === $val) 
            {
                      return $key;
            }
        }
    }

foreach($array2->result() as $row)
        {
            $id = $row->id;
            $same_sku = $row->same_sku;

            $key = $this->search_array($array1, $id); 

            if(!empty($key))
            {
                $same_sku_key = $this->search_array($array1, $same_sku);
                if(!empty($same_sku_key))
                    unset($array1[$same_sku_key]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tired so far ? Can you share your code ?

Comment: @Nirnae I have added what I have tired

Comment: Are you trying to combine the two arrays and remove the duplicate values?

Comment: @nullReference no I have two different array that has different structure as you can see from my example. I am not sure I can achieve what I need by combining array

Comment: So you have an array of products with ids, array1, and you need to remove from array1 all of the sub arrays that have an id that match the value of "same_sku" within array2? Is this correct?

Comment: @nullReference yes that is exactly what I need

Comment: @nullReference however both array are multidimensional and has other value other than ids

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I have recreated the two arrays from your example. I then created a function that removes from a haystack array (array1) all of the sub arrays that have an "id" that matches the value of "same_sku" within a needle array (array2). The final line echos the result array.

**EDIT**
I have modified the original answer to pass the array values by reference and unset the unwanted sub arrays, instead of passing by value, looping, and returning another array. This should resolve the memory issue, as well as the other issue mentioned in your comment.

```
$array1 = array(
    array(
        'id'                    => 'et1',
        'supplier_id'           => '4',
        'supplier_product_code' => '00054X',
        'is_active'             => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'id'                    => 'et2',
        'supplier_id'           => '4',
        'supplier_product_code' => '000558',
        'is_active'             => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'id'                    => 'et3',
        'supplier_id'           => '5',
        'supplier_product_code' => '00054X',
        'is_active'             => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'id'                    => 'et4',
        'supplier_id'           => '5',
        'supplier_product_code' => '00054X',
        'is_active'             => '1'
    )
);

$array2 = array(
    array(
        'id'                    => 'et1',
        'same_sku'              => 'et3'
    ),
    array(
        'id'                    => 'et2',
        'same_sku'              => 'et4'
    )
);


function remove_same_sku(&$haystack, &$needles){

    foreach($needles as $needle){

        foreach($haystack as $key => $val){

            if($val['id'] === $needle['same_sku']){

                unset($haystack[$key]);

            }

        }

    }


}

remove_same_sku($array1, $array2);
echo print_r($array1);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but the problem I see there is that wont I need another function to check if the $haystack[$key] is not already in $returnArray[] and only then add it ?

Comment: I used the function and it is running out of memory and I think it is doing that because it inserts all the data from $haystack where id is not same_sku. So for example if the first loop is on same_sku et3 it will insert all the data from $haystack where id is not equal to $et3 and then move to the next increment and do the same again.